# Django Model Save() method with related instance update

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am probably a medium Django user with quite a lot of RTFM under my belt.

I have a workflow that is roughly this:

1. Retrieve an *account* (model) object.
2. Perform actions on the *account* object (update fields, etc.)
3. Create a related *usage* (model) object using *account* as foreign key.
4. Update the *account* object as part of a custom save() on the *usage* object.
5. (Save any changes to *account* made in step 2).

**Models**:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    ...
    credit_balance = models.IntegerField(...)
    ...

class Usage(models.Model):
    ...
    account = models.ForeignKey(Account, ...)
    credit_balance = models.IntegerField(...)
    ...

    def save( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        """Custom usage save to update account stats."""
        if self.account:
            self.account.credit_balance = self.credit_balance
            self.account.save()
```

**Code in various functions / methods**:

```
account = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)

[do something to account]

usage = Usage.objects.create(account = account,
                             tariff_short_name = account.tariff.short_name,
                             **customer_data['usage'])
```

What I am really struggling to work out is if I need to do:

```
account.save()
```

At this point, and what the implications are?

It seems that the changes I have made to *account* (e.g. in step 2) are saved when I save the related *account* object in the *usage* object custom save method.

Why? How does the *usage* object "know" what the current state of the instantiated *account* object is?

I was expecting to have to subsequently save the *account* object, potentially with save(update_fields=[]) to prevent overwriting the *usage* object update to the *account* model.

Sorry this is so esoteric - I just don't understand the behaviour of Django here. I can's seem to find it in tfm and my googling is not working as I am not sure what I am looking for.

Comment: Seems right that when you do `self.account.save()`, it will update the local variable `account` as you updated some fields on it before passing to `create` method of `UsageManager`.

Comment: And I am struggling to understand, why you are updating the account in two different places. One, before creating the `Usage` instance and two, while creating the same instance. Cant you just update the fields before or after creating the instance of `Usage` and call `account.save`.

Comment: Hi Sachin, thanks for the reply. At present I am not calling the last account.save() and all of my previous updates to account are being saved when the usage.save() method is called. e.g. it is working how I want it to, I just don't know why. How does a Usage model method (save()) know what changes I have made to the account instance previously?

Comment: Because they are the same object. You passed in `account` when you called `Usage.objects.create`, and that Usage object then stores it as `self.account` and updates it. But it still relates to exactly the same object in memory. This is nothing to do with Django, just normal Python behaviour.

Comment: To expand on Daniel Roseman's comment, note that `create()` is just shorthand for instantiating an instance of the model and then calling `save()` on it. So a `Usage` object is created; its `account` attribute is set to the account you passed; `Usage.save()` is called; which, per your code above, triggers `self.account.save()`.

Comment: Ahh ok, now I understand. Thank you Daniel and Kevin. So I pass in the `account` object (with any changes made since instantiating it) to `Usage.objects.create()`, which then calls Usage.save() in which `self.account` references the `account` object I have passed to it. I think I was expecting the Usage `self.account` to reference the database relationship (and as such retrieve the related account) rather than an the object in memory that I had passed. Sorry for my misunderstanding of this behaviour and thank you for your time.